# Is there a way to select multiple files in Astro File Manager

Tags: files, astro-file-manager

I want to delete multiple files with astro file manager. Is there a way to select many files at once? (like holding ctrl+click in windows)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Press the "Multi" button and then select the files/folders you want, [as explained on their help site](http://support.metago.net/entries/20323943-how-do-i-choose-multiple-files):

> To select multiple files in ASTRO you simply click the "Multi" button.
>   Then, you choose the files or folders you would like to work with (you
>   will know they are selected because the names will turn orange.  If
>   you want to copy or move files, go to the location you want those
>   files and press the Copy or Move buttons.  If you want to delete,
>   simply press the delete button and they will be removed.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there is. Tap the "multi" button in the tool bar at the top.